# Will returning an array from a function cause a memory leak?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Since we cannot free the local pointer "tmparr" which defining in the function, will it cause memory leak?  Not sure is it any better coding solution here.

I am trying to pass a pointer to a function, so that it will process and change the data inside the function as well.  The size of the data and value can flexible modify within the function.

```
void printArray(int* data, 
                int length)
{
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {

        if ((i>0) && (i%5==0))
            printf("\n");

        printf("%d ", data[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

}

void copyPassPtrArray(int** data,
                      int length)
{
    int* tmparr = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        tmparr[i] = i + 10;

    *data = tmparr;
}


int main()
{
    int length = 10;

    int* ptrarr = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));

    for (int i =0; i <length; i++)
        ptrarr[i] = i;

    printf("Origin ... \n");
    printArray(ptrarr, length);

    copyPassPtrArray(&ptrarr, 20);
    printf("After copyPassPtrArray ... \n");
    printArray(ptrarr, 20);

    free(ptrarr);

    return 0;
}
```

---

After reading the comments, I have the following proposed api solution.  The purpose of this practice is that we may not know what will the size of an array and values after certain computation in the function.  It "data" need to return back to main or other function. However, is there anymore memory leak?

```
void copyGlobalPtrArray(int** data,
                        int length)
{   
    *data = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        (*data)[i] = i + 10;
}
```

Comment: You allocate memory for `ptrarr` twice, and free it only once; so yes, this will result in a memory leak. (You can also try it out and measure it, e.g. using valgrind).

Comment: *If* you allocate memory in a function that is not freed in that function (usually not recommended), *return* that data from the function, so that you have an explicit value to assign to at the point of the function call. That makes it clearer what variable to free.

Comment: Great. Yours feedback did certainly enlighten me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not too sure whether you have written code which is free from memory leak problem then its a good practice to use memory leak tool

valgrind is one the tool which can be used .

below is the command :

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full  ./memleak  (program name)
==422== Command: ./memleak
Origin ... 
0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9 
After copyPassPtrArray ...
10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 
25 26 27 28 29 

==422== HEAP SUMMARY:
==422==     in use at exit: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==422==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 120 bytes allocated  // here total allocations n free done  in ur code

==422== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==422==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==422==    by 0x400767: main (memleak.c:35)    //shows line number 

==422== LEAK SUMMARY:
==422==    definitely lost: 40 bytes in 1 blocks  // here u can see memory leak
==422==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 block
==422==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==422==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==422==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==422== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So its better to run this and try to solve memory leak yourself

Comment: Noted. I heard of "valgrind", will install and try it out. Thank you for teaching me - "how to fish".  Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a leak.
But it's not where you think it is.

You have correctly `free`'d the area allocated in `copyPassPtrArray`.
However, the originally allocated pointer,

```
int* ptrarr = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
```

has not been freed.
That is because you over-wrote the original data's pointer in the line

```
copyPassPtrArray(&ptrarr, 20);
```

The old pointer is lost forever! 
Instead, you should store into a new pointer, and free both pointers at the end.

e.g.

```
int main()
{
    int length = 10;

    int* ptrarr = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int);
    int* copyarr;

    for (int i =0; i <length; i++)
        ptrarr[i] = i;

    printf("Origin ... \n");
    printArray(ptrarr, length);

    copyPassPtrArray(&copyarr, 20);     // put copied pointer into a separate variable
    printf("After copyPassPtrArray ... \n");
    printArray(copyarr, 20);

    free(ptrarr);
    free(copyarr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The purpose of passing "ptrarr" into the function, which the function may need to refer the array of the values for the computation, at the meantime, it may rewrite values and resize the array in the function itself.  At the end, the function reuses back the memory buffer and return back to main or other function.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, it's not a good idea to allocate memory inside a function that is not freed inside the same function. Better, allocate the memory for a variable outside the function, pass the variable to the function, and free the variable outside the function as well.

Something like this:

```
void copyPassPtrArray(int *tmparr, int length)
{
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        tmparr[i] = i + 10;
}


int main()
{
    int length = 10;
    int doublelength = 2 * length;

    int* ptrarr = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int* newarr = (int*)malloc(doublelength * sizeof(int));

    for (int i =0; i <length; i++)
        ptrarr[i] = i;

    ...

    copyPassPtrArray(newarr, doublelength);

    ...

    free(newarr);
    free(ptrarr);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to allocate memory inside a function, explicitly return that memory in a variable, and assign it to a (new) variable.

Then your code could be something like:

```
int *copyPassPtrArray(int length)
{
    int* tmparr = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        tmparr[i] = i + 10;

    return tmparr;
}


int main()
{
    int length = 10;

    int* ptrarr = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int* newarr = NULL;

    for (int i =0; i <length; i++)
        ptrarr[i] = i;

    ...

    newarr = copyPassPtrArray(20);

    ...

    free(newarr)
    free(ptrarr);

    return 0;
}
```

If you now would have the line `ptrarr = copyPassPtrArray(20);` instead, you would easier notice you're overriding/reassigning `ptrarr`, since it's in the same block as its earlier allocation.

Comment: If the function's task is to allocate memory for use outside the function, it is not necessary to release the allocated memory inside the function.  But if the function is not required to return the extra allocated memory, then it is indeed responsible for freeing what it allocates.